# How can i get my outgoing payments in paypal api?

Tags: node.js, paypal

I use [PayPal-node-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK)

To get my transactions i use this method:

```
var listPayment = {
    'count': '1',
    'start_index': '1'
};

paypal.payment.list(listPayment, function (error, payment) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log("List Payments Response");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(payment));
    }
});
```

But i get only incoming payments.
How can i get my outgoing payments?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The PayPal-Node-SDK is deprecated. Do not use it for anything.

For checkout API calls specifically, there is a [Checkout-NodeJS-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NodeJS-SDK) ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/checkout-server-sdk))

For *all other, non-checkout* APIs, use direct HTTPS calls (no SDK). It's not clear what your need is in listing "payments" -- you might be looking for the [Transaction Search API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/transaction-search/).